# use a javascript function variable in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript function. It has a variable that takes a particular value (entered by user). I need to insert this value in an sql database. I know I cannot use javascript to connect to database, I need to use php for that. Can you tell me how to do that? Just explain, I will write the code. I mean, do i need to create a new php file (but then if i create a new php sheet,then how can i access this variable bcz its in an all together different php sheet) or can I write in the same file, stuff like this....

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need an AJAX call to a separate PHP file to process the script and return the values to the JavaScript.